# special unicode character in html2pdf

Tags: php, html2pdf

I want to transform a document that contains the special unicode character '✝' from html to pdf with html2pf. However, when the document is rendered, '✝' is displayed as '?'. What can I do about that?

Comment: You can try `utf8_encode / utf8_decode` functions. Or, use `&#134;` notation.

Comment: unfortunately, both do not work

Comment: The font you are using probably doesn’t contain that character. I could get it to work with `dejavusans`. Here’s a [snippet](http://pastie.org/private/j7ynkeo8ywyqg8gs2zug) for a quick test.

Answer (score 3):

The "✝" (U+271D LATIN CROSS) character probably cannot be rendered correctly in the PDF document because the used font does not support it.

Here are some ideas:

1) Replace the character with a more common one that looks similar. "†" (U+2020 DAGGER) would be an obvious choice as it is part of the common Windows-1252 charset.

In code:

```
$var = str_replace("\xE2\x9C\x9D", "\xE2\x80\xA0", $var);
```

`$var` has to contain data encoded in UTF-8. Besides that, I always prefer to insert more “uncommon” characters into source code by using their binary representation. One reason is: Many editor fonts don’t contain such characters either. It prevents problems.

2) Change the font of the PDF document to a font that supports the character. Here’s an example (same as the snippet from my comment to the question):

```
$font = 'dejavusans';

$content = <<<EOT
<page>
<h1>$font</h1>
\xE2\x9C\x9D U+271D LATIN CROSS
</page>
EOT;

require_once __DIR__ . '/html2pdf_v4.03/html2pdf.class.php';

$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF();
$html2pdf->setDefaultFont($font);
$html2pdf->WriteHTML($content);
$html2pdf->Output(__DIR__ . '/test.pdf', 'F');
```

3) If you want the original character in the PDF document and don’t want to change your default font, you can switch to a font that supports the character whenever you encounter one.

```
$input = <<<EOT
<h1>Demo</h1>
<p>This should be Arial.</p>
<p>\xE2\x9C\x9D - U+271D LATIN CROSS</p>
EOT;

$input = str_replace(
    "\xE2\x9C\x9D",
    "<span style=\"font-family: dejavusans\">\xE2\x9C\x9D</span>",
    $input
);

$content = <<<EOT
<page>
$input
</page>
EOT;

require_once __DIR__ . '/html2pdf_v4.03/html2pdf.class.php';

$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF();
$html2pdf->setDefaultFont('arial');
$html2pdf->addFont('dejavusans');    // note this line
$html2pdf->WriteHTML($content);
$html2pdf->Output(__DIR__ . '/test.pdf', 'F');
```

Rendered PDF output:

[image: example]

Solutions 2 and 3 have one rather big disadvantage, though. You’ll probably have to embed the additional font into the PDF document (which html2pdf does by default), increasing its size by quite a bit.

There is a feature in PDF and tcpdf (which html2pdf is built upon) to only add the characters from a font that actually occur in a document (called a subset), but html2pdf doesn’t expose this feature, as far as I can tell.

In case you need to support a lot of uncommon Unicode characters, solution 2 is probably the way to go.